# nestjs mongoose Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<LeanDocument<User>>

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Im using nestjs with mongoose. I try to do a simple find query

```
 this.challengesModel.find({ createdBy: userId })
```

where this.challengesModel is injected like this

```
 private readonly challengesModel: Model<Challenge>
```

but it says

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<LeanDocument<User>>'
```

createdBy is considered as a User object whereas I am giving it a string(userId)
How can I still keep the createdBy field as User by search only by the id?

This is my schema

```
@Schema()
export class Challenge extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" })
  createdBy: User;

  @Prop()
  description: string;

  @Prop({ default: new Date() })
  creationTime: Date;

  @Prop()
  video: string;

  @Prop({ default: [] })
  likes: string[];

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }] })
  selectedFriends: User[];

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Reply" }] })
  replies: Reply[];
}
```

The createdBy is saved as a unique id of the user (foreign key to the users collection)
I am trying to perform a query to find challenges that were created by a user with specific id.
If I change createdBy to be a string(id) it works, but then I don't get all the user properties, also the nest documentation suggests to create it like I did.
What should I change in order to be able to do this find without any compliation errors?

Comment: try something like : `this.challengesModel.find({ createdBy: new ObjectId(userId)})` may be this will create an objectId from a string

Comment: managed to make it work with this.challengesModel.find({ createdBy: userId } as FilterQuery<Challenge>)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 this.challengesModel.find({ createdBy: userId as any })
```

This is caused because createdBy isn't a string type.